# How to get the values returned from a a group by aggregate query as zero, (0), when a count of the field is zero?

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a value returned (in this case a zero) from the query for types in the event that a count of Table.id is zero.

```
 SELECT COUNT(Table1.id) AS AccountID, Table2.typeName AS Types
 FROM Table1
 LEFT JOIN Table3
 ON Table1.productID = Table3.productID
 LEFT JOIN Table2
 ON Table3.categoryID = Table2.CategoryID
 WHERE Table3.account_id = 51
 GROUP BY Table2.typeName;
```

[This is the result that I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11sZm.png)

[This is the result that I am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B6U3.png)

```
Table1
id      ProductID
1       1
1       1
2       2
2       1
1       1
id in this table 1 references categoryID in table2
---------------------------------------------------------

Table2
categoryID      typeName
1               SUV
2               BMW
3               Toyota
4               Audi
5               Suzuki
---------------------------------------------------------


Table3
categoryID      ProductID       account_id
2               1               51
1               2               52
3               1               51
categoryID is table3 references categoryID in table2
----------------------------------------------------------


My expected result should look like this

Count   Types
0       Toyota
0       Audi
0       Suzuki
3       SUV
2       BMW
```

I want a count of all the id(s) from table1 with its corresponding typeName. If the id is not present, I want the a 0 to be returned with the corresponding typeName.

Comment: Your filter `Table3.account_id = 51` turns your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.  Try to move the `WHERE` condition to `ON` clause.

Comment: Do you want total count for each typename or only for `account_id = 51`?

Comment: Only for account_id = 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will work:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(Table1.id) AS AccountID, 
 Table2.typeName  AS Types
 FROM Table2
 LEFT JOIN Table3
 ON Table3.categoryID = Table2.CategoryID
 AND Table3.account_id = 51
 LEFT JOIN Table1
 ON Table1.id = Table3.CategoryID     
 GROUP BY Table2.typeName;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://rextester.com/JNUL92135)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157948/discussion-on-answer-by-harshil-how-to-get-the-values-returned-from-a-a-group-by).